# Can Boto assume roles via EKS Service Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-eks

We currenlty use: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

We have a few legacy services running on EC2 instances, using boto (not boto3) .. they are all using an IAM role on the instance.

Since boto is old, I havent been able to find any information on whether or not a boto application can use the EKS Service Account IAM Roles.

my Initial test, using our existing framework, results in the the application not getting the AWS permissions.

Answer (score 3):

AWS has documentation for minimum supported SDK : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts-minimum-sdk.html.

I actually got bitten by using old version of aws-cli and wasn't working and wasting lots of time on it.

For boto below are minimum supported version

```
Python (Boto3) — 1.9.220

Python (botocore) — 1.12.200
```